# How do you access enum values in Rust?

Tags: rust

```
struct Point {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

enum Shape {
    Circle(Point, f64),
    Rectangle(Point, Point),
}

let my_shape = Shape::Circle(Point { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 }, 10.0);
```

I want to print out `circle`'s second property, which is 10.0 here.
I tried `my_shape.last` and `my_shape.second`, but neither worked.

What should I do in order to print out 10.0 in this case?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use pattern matching:

```
struct Point {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

enum Shape {
    Circle(Point, f64),
    Rectangle(Point, Point),
}

fn main() {
    let my_shape = Shape::Circle(Point { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 }, 10.0);

    match my_shape {
        Shape::Circle(_, value) => println!("value: {}", value),
        _ => println!("Something else"),
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
value: 10
```

Answer (score 112):

As you are only interested in matching one of the variants, you can use an `if let` expression instead of a `match`:

```
struct Point {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

enum Shape {
    Circle(Point, f64),
    Rectangle(Point, Point),
}

fn main() {
    let my_shape = Shape::Circle(Point { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 }, 10.0);

    if let Shape::Circle(_, radius) = my_shape {
        println!("value: {}", radius);
    }
}
```

This means "if `my_shape` can be destructured into a `Circle`, do nothing with the first index, but bind the value of the second index to `radius`".

Answer (score 33):

Here is another way to do it:

```
struct Point {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

enum Shape {
    Circle(Point, f64),
}

fn main() {
    let Shape::Circle(_, radius) = Shape::Circle(Point { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 }, 10.0);
    println!("value: {}", radius);
}
```

This only works if the pattern is irrefutable, such as when the enum type you're matching on only has one variant. To make this work, I had to remove the unused `Rectangle` variant.

In cases where you have more than one variant, you'll probably want the full match expression anyway, since you're presumably handling more than just one kind of shape.

Comment: Good attempt, but considering they have `Rectangle` in the first place, they're just.... probably.... gonna use it.
Though, it's still valid in the same regard as @user1038550 and @jcollado's answers.

Answer (score 11):

From [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch06-02-match.html#patterns-that-bind-to-values):

> Another useful feature of match arms is that they can bind to parts of the values that match the pattern. This is how we can extract values out of enum variants.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> fn value_in_cents(coin: Coin) -> u32 {
>     match coin {
>         Coin::Penny => 1,
>         Coin::Nickel => 5,
>         Coin::Dime => 10,
>         Coin::Quarter(state) => {
>             println!("State quarter from {:?}!", state);
>             25
>         },
>     }
> }
> ```

If you'd like to be able to write functions that are capable of working on multiple types with different representations, have a look at [traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-02-traits.html).

Answer (score 6):

For a simple retrieval of value, you can use "if let"

```
let mut var: f64 = 0.0;
if let Shape::Circle(_, float1) = my_shape {
    var = float1;
}
println!("value is {}", var);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
let r = match my_shape { Shape::Circle(_, r) => r, _ => 0f64 };
```

or

```
let r = if let Shape::Circle(_, r) = my_shape { r } else { 0f64 };
```

Answer (score 5):

[Rust 1.65.0 brings us let-else](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/11/03/Rust-1.65.0.html#let-else-statements) which let you access a single enum variant in a new way with less nesting than match or if-let:

```rust
fn main() {
    let my_shape = Shape::Circle(Point { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 }, 10.0);

    let Shape::Circle(_, radius) = my_shape else { return; };
    println!("value: {radius}");
}

struct Point {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

enum Shape {
    Circle(Point, f64),
    Rectangle(Point, Point),
}
```

The `else` branch of a `let else` has to be diverging, that means it must execute either of:

- a diverging keyword `return`, `continue`, `break`
- an infinite `loop`
- a `panic!`
- a function returning `!`, the never type

or any other diverging statement

Answer (score -2):

You can also define a method on your enum (e.g. `unwrap_radius`) and then call it:

```rust
struct Point {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
}

enum Shape {
    Circle(Point, f64),
    Rectangle(Point, Point),
}

impl Shape {
    fn unwrap_radius(self) -> f64 {
        match self {
            Shape::Circle(_, r) => r,
            _ => 0.0,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_shape = Shape::Circle(Point { x: 0.0, y: 0.0 }, 10.0);
    println!("{}", my_shape.unwrap_radius());
}
```