# Result and Option unwrapping

Tags: rust

I am trying to learn Rust and I would like to understand the conceptual fundamentals. In Rust, we often use `Result<T, E>` as a return type. Basically, a type, which consists of - `Ok()` and `Err()`, and it is up to the caller to handle these.

But what I am kind a surprised is fact, that both `Ok()` and `Err()`, have again their "options" -> Namely `Some` and `None`.

### Example code:

```
fn integer_divide(a: u32, b: u32) -> Result<u32, String> {
  if b != 0 {
    Ok(a / b)
  } else {
    Err("Division by zero!".into())
  }
} 

let result = integer_divide(5, 0);

if(result.is_err()){
    if(result.err().is_some()){
        // some logic
    }
}
```

### Question

So basically, we need to double check before we get to resulting value of every function (First for `Err` or `Ok`, then for `Some` or `None`)? If yes, I find this very clunky. Especially in case my `integer_divide` function, where reliably I am able to say, it can never have a result with `Err()` of `None` value.

It would make more sense to me, if we would just unwrap `Err()`, then check if it's value is `None` or some other type... Especially in case, where I am 100% sure, it cannot hold `None` value. Any thoughts appreciated.

### Note

I am aware of existence of `?` operator. I just want to understand concept.

Comment: `Result` and `Option` are enums. See [How do you access enum values in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109872/how-do-you-access-enum-values-in-rust)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering `result.err()` alone, nothing ensures that `result` actually contains an error, thus this method cannot return an error every time we invoke it.
The usual way in Rust to provide something which is optional is to return an `Option`, hence the `is_some()` method.
This does not mean that the `Result` contains such an `Option`; this `Option` is created by the `err()` method just in case `result` did not contain an error.
**You** know that there is actually an error inside `result` because you tested just before with `result.is_err()`; but the designer of the `err()` method did not know, a long time ago, that **you** would test `is_err()` just before calling `err()`.

The usual way to handle `result` without double check would be

```rust
    match result {
        Ok(v) => {
            println!("result is {}", v);
        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("error: {}", e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`is_err()` serves to answer the question "does this result contain an error?". If that's all you're interested in, then you're good to go:

```
if result.is_err() {
    // logic here
}
```

`Result` is just an enum with two well-defined variants, so if you also need to access the *value* of the error, you can use `if let` to match the `Err` variant:

```
if let Err(e) = result {
   // logic here, `e` contains the error value
}
```

Finally, if you need to handle both `Ok` and `Err` in the same go, use `match`, as shown in the answer by @prog-fh.