# Why can't I access enum fields directly?

Tags: rust, enums

I'm just learning Rust.
So I know this works:

```
enum Animal {
    Cat { name: String, weight: f64 }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Animal::Cat { name: "Spotty".to_string(), weight: 2.7 };
    match a {
        Animal::Cat{name, weight} => { println!("Cat n={} w={}", name, weight); }
    }
}
```

but why can I not assign from an enum field directly like this:

```
    ...
    let wt = a.weight;
```

Or am I using the wrong syntax? Or is it because Rust cannot guarantee an `Animal` instance will be of type `Cat`?
Is the only way to access fields of an instance of enum struct or tuple variant by using `match`?

Comment: Relevant: [How do you access enum values in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9109872); [the book on "Patterns that bind to values"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html#patterns-that-bind-to-values)

Answer (score 4):

It is because `weight` isn't part of the `Animal` enum, it's part of the `Cat` type of the enum. Say in the future you add another type of animal that doesn't have weight information:

```rust
enum Animal {
    Cat { name: String, weight: f64 },
    Insect { species: String, height: f64 },
}
```

Then `a.weight` wouldn't always have a value. You can use `if let` or `match` to conditionally get data from an `enum` if it exists:

```rust
if let Animal::Cat { weight, .. } = a {
    println!("Your cat weights {} kg.", weight);
} else {
    println!("get a cat");
};
```

Comment: Correction: `Cat` is not a type, it's an item (/ variant / constructor). The idea of making variants into types [is a recurring one](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2593) but as of March 2021 that is very much not the case.

Answer (score 2):

> Or is it because Rust cannot guarantee an Animal instance will be of type Cat?

Yes. In a normal enum, you'd have multiple variants, which may or may not have the same types, and thus fields (in fact some may not have fields at all).

So while it would technically be possible for rust to have attribute access on enums with a single variant or where all variants have a compatible version of the attribute, those are such rare cases they don't really matter and the value of such complexity would be essentially nil.

I don't rightly see the point of using a single-variant enum tho, why are you not just using a struct?

```rust
struct Cat { name: String, weight: f64 }
```

?

> Is the only way to access fields of an instance of enum struct or tuple variant by using match?

You could also use an `if let` though that's essentially the same.
Or you can have a method which exposes the information (with a `match` or `if let` inside), as convenience (or because the variants are private).

Comment: In my real-world code I have several variants. Just wanted to post a boiled-down version.

Comment: @user1088084 If all `Animal`s have a `weight`, consider combining `struct Animal { weight: f64, species: Species }` with `enum Species { Cat { name: String }, Squirrel { color: Color } }` or something like that instead of trying to shove it all into a flat enum. Structs and enums are called *algebraic data types* because they follow rules similar to numbers in some ways: `(weight*name)+(weight*color)` can be simplified to `weight + (name*color)`.

Comment: Um, I factored that completely backwards, it should obviously be `weight*(name+color)`. This message brought to you by lack of sleep