# How do you push values to a vec inside an enum stuct in Rust?

Tags: rust

How do you push values to a vec inside an enum stuct in Rust?

I'm trying to figure out how to push values to a vec inside an enum that's defined as a struct.

Here's the setup along with some of the stuff I tried:

```rust
enum Widget {
    Alfa { strings: Vec<String> },
}

fn main() {
    let wa = Widget::Alfa { strings: vec![] };

    // wa.strings.push("a".to_string()); 
    // no field `strings` on type `Widget`

    // wa.Alfa.strings.push("a".to_string()); 
    // no field `Alfa` on type `Widget`

    // wa.alfa.strings.push("a".to_string()); 
    // no field `alfa` on type `Widget`

    // wa.Widget::Alfa.strings.push("a".to_string()); 
    // expected one of `(`, `.`, `;`, `?`, `}`, or an operator, found `::`

    // wa["strings"].push("a".to_string()); 
    // cannot index into a value of type `Widget`
}
```

Is it possible to update a vec in an emum after it's been created? If so how does one go about that?

*(NOTE: It was suggested that this is a duplicate of [How do you access enum values in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9109872/102401). I looked at that but it didn't address my question. It addresses how to *access* values, not how to *update* them. The two things are related, but the solution in the other answer for accessing does not accommodate updating.)*

Comment: You'll need to use `match` (or `if let`) so the compiler knows which variant is considered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't access the fields on an enum variant directly, because the compiler only knows that the value is of the enum type (`Widget`), not which variant of the enum it has. You have to destructure the enum, for example with a `match`:

```rust
let mut wa = Widget::Alfa { strings: vec![] };

match &mut wa {
    Widget::Alfa { strings /*: &mut Vec<String> */ } => {
        strings.push("a".to_string());
    }

    // if the enum has more variants, you must have branches for these as well.
    // if you only care about `Widget::Alfa`, a wildcard branch like this is often a
    // good choice.
    _ => unreachable!(), // panics if ever reached, which we know in this case it won't
                         // because we just assigned `wa` before the `match`.
}
```

Alternatively you can use `if let` instead:

```rust
let mut wa = Widget::Alfa { strings: vec![] };

if let Widget::Alfa { strings } = &mut wa {
    strings.push("a".to_string());
} else {
    // some other variant than `Widget::Alfa`, equivalent to the wildcard branch
    // of the `match`. you can omit this, which would just do nothing
    // if it doesn't match.
    unreachable!()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this if you have one matching arm (which has no sense):

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Widget {
    Alfa { strings: Vec<String> },
}

fn main() {
    let mut wa = Widget::Alfa { strings: vec![] };

    let Widget::Alfa { strings } = &mut wa;
    
    strings.push("X".to_string());
    strings.push("Y".to_string());

    println!("{:?}", wa);
}
```

Or by using `match` (`if let`):

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Widget {
    Alfa { strings: Vec<String> },
    Beta { string: Vec<String> }
}

fn main() {
    let mut wa = Widget::Alfa { strings: vec![] };

    if let Widget::Alfa { strings } = &mut wa {
        strings.push("X".to_string());
        strings.push("Y".to_string());
    }

    println!("{:?}", wa);
}
```